# WebDAV and sharepoint server subscription edition

Tags: sharepoint-server, webdav

good morning, is WebDAV still working on SharePoint subscription edition? Because when I clicked Open with Explorer it is trying to use OneDrive instead of the UNC path.
i already added the site in Trusted Sites and used the IE compatibility mode.
also i installed the webdav publishing feature on the server
i tried this path \server.domain.org@ssl\DavWWWRoot\ too
but unfortunatly still not working
can you suggest a solution please or advice
thank you in advance

Comment: Are you using classic or modern experience?

Comment: classic experiance

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution maybe it can help someone in the future :)
(my environnement: windows server 2019, sharepoint server subscription edition)

> Enable WebDAV Redirector
> Enable the WebClient Service to Automatic" Startup Type
> Enable the Portable Device Enumerator Service to Automatic Startup Type
> Disable WebDAV Authoring Rules on your site on the IIS
> try to connect from \yourserver.domain.org@ssl\DavWWWRoot\